# Is every finite subset of a metric space closed?

Tags: metric-spaces

> Is  every finite  subset of a metric space  closed ? Yes/No

## My attempt : i think No

Consider $X = \{0, 1\}$ with the indiscrete metrics i.e. the ***only two*** open sets are $\emptyset$ and $X = \{0, 1\}$ itself.

the singleton subset $\{0\}$ of $X$ is not closed because its complement $X \setminus \{0\} = \{1\}$ is not one of the two open sets listed above and therefore not open.

Is its true ?

Comment: There is no such thing as an indiscrete metric (unless, of course, you are considering it on the topological spaces $\{0\}$ or $\emptyset$).

Comment: You seem to be mixing up metric and topology.

Comment: okss@Gae.S. but that is definition of indiscrete  metrics

Comment: That space isn't Hausdorff, so it can't be a metric space.

Comment: This is an indiscrete topology, not indiscrete metric. Such a topological space is not metrizable. And by the way, the statement is actually true. Try to prove that a singleton is closed in a metric space, then use the fact that a finite union of closed sets is closed.

Comment: *but that is definition of indiscrete metrics* --- An explicit citation that can be examined by others would go a long way towards understanding the nature of your confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\{p_1,...,p_n\} \subset X$ and $x \notin F$. Let $\epsilon = \min_kd(x,p_k)$. Then $B(x,\epsilon) \cap F = \emptyset$ and so $F^c$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $x\in X$ be given. For each $x\neq y\in X$ define $O_y = B(y, d(x, y))$. Note that each $O_y$ is open, contains $y$, and does not contain $x$. Then $O = \bigcup_{y\neq x} O_y$ is open and $O = X\setminus \{x\}$. So $\{x\}$ is closed as the complement of an open set.

Now let $x_1, \ldots, x_n\in X$ be given. From the previous paragraph each $\{x_i\}$ is closed, so $\bigcup_{i = 1}^n \{x_i\} = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ is closed as the finite union of closed sets.